# What is the correct usage of the AVG() function in this situation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query which gives me two columns - one column is Years (ranging from 1997 to 2017) and the other column is the tenure of an employee by months.

```
Select  DATEPART(YEAR,Cast(USI.StartDate As Date)) AS Year,
        DATEDIFF(MONTH,Cast(USI.StartDate As Date),Cast(USI.EndDate As Date)) AS TenureInMonths
From    UserWorkHistory      UWH
Join    Users                U    On UWH.UserId = U.Id
Join    UserStoryItems       USI  On U.Id = USI.UserId
Join    UserWorkHistoryTypes UWHT On UWH.UserWorkHistoryTypeId = UWHT.Id
Where   
(
    U.Location Like '%Great Britain%'
 Or U.Location Like '%United Kingdom%'
 Or U.Location Like '%England%'
 Or U.Location Like '%UK%'
 Or U.Location Like '%U.K.%'
)
and    UWHT.Id = 1
And    USI.UserStoryItemTypeId = 1
And    Cast(USI.StartDate As Date) > DateAdd(Year, -20, GetDate())
And 
(
     (
        UWH.Role NOT LIKE '%Contract%'
     Or UWH.Role NOT LIKE '%Contractor%'
     Or UWH.Role NOT LIKE '%Freelance%'
     Or UWH.Role NOT LIKE '%Non-perm%'
     Or UWH.Role NOT LIKE '%non-permanent%'
    )
    Or 
    (
        USI.Title NOT LIKE '%Contract%'
     Or USI.Title NOT LIKE '%Contractor%'
     Or USI.Title NOT LIKE '%Freelance%'
     Or USI.Title NOT LIKE '%Non-perm%'
     Or USI.Title NOT LIKE '%non-permanent%'
     Or USI.Title NOT LIKE '%self-made%'
     Or USI.Title NOT LIKE '%(Contract)%'
    )
)
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,Cast(USI.StartDate As Date)), Cast(USI.StartDate As Date), Cast(USI.EndDate As Date)      
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,Cast(USI.StartDate As Date))
```

What I want to do is find the average tenure per employee based on the year they started. For example, the average tenure in months for an employee who started in 1997 rather than 2012.

I understand for this that the AVG() function needs to be used, however I am unsure about how to execute it with ALL the years in the year column, rather than just adding

```
AVG(DATEDIFF(MONTH,Cast(USI.StartDate As Date),Cast(USI.EndDate As Date))) AS AVERAGE
```

which doesn't give me the average per year.

I also understand that the GROUP BY clause is necessary here, but I can't GROUP BY just the YEAR, as the Cast(USI.StartDate As Date), Cast(USI.EndDate As Date) need to be included.

Comment: Is the `group by` that is in your original script necessary in the script as is?

Comment: Yes, without any of the additional GROUP BY the CAST STARTDATE and CAST ENDDATE I get error messages saying I need to include them. One option I suppose is finding the appropriate place in the query where they occur and deleting this, thus being able to only GROUP BY Year. However I can't find where...

Comment: I don't mean the additional `group by`s to do the `average`, I mean the ones that are already in the script you have provided, which doesn't do any aggregation at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very tricky to debug without the original data available, but have you tried replacing:

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH,Cast(USI.StartDate As Date),Cast(USI.EndDate As Date)) AS TenureInMonths
```

with something like:

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH,Min(Cast(USI.StartDate As Date)),Max(Cast(USI.EndDate As Date))) AS TenureInMonths
```

which would allow you to remove the start and end dates from the GROUP BY?

Comment: Like I said, very difficult because we don't know what the data is and don't fully know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew - that worked! Excuse me for not asking correctly, I'm still new at this. But what you recommended worked perfectly.

Comment: @BadAtCoding That's good to hear! I'm glad to have been of help.